# QuickTime save as m4a

Tags: macos, quicktime

I opened an m4a, I trimmed it (cmd t), now I want to save the new audio.

For some reason it's forcing me to save as MOV, instead of allowing me to save as m4a (the original format in the first place).

I discovered that choosing to overwrite an existing m4a file works, no MOV extension.

However, choosing to save as a new file seems to require MOV file extension.

How can I save as m4a for new file?